# How to create a generic method to accommodate any number of POJOs

Tags: java, android, generics

I want to use generics to instantiate common data held in various POJOs. The POJOs are structured like this,

```
public class A extends BasePojo {
   public String firstName;
} 

public class B extends BasePojo {
   public String lastName;
} 

public class BasePojo {
   public String middleName;
   public String gender;
}
```

What I want to do is set the middleName and gender in the BasePojo via a generic method.

```
// this method is what I need help creating, it is not correct.
public static Class<? extends BasePojo > setData(Class<T> pojo) {
   pojo.middleName = "Jason";
   pojo.gender = "male";
}
```

What is the proper implementation for this scenario? I want to be able to pass in Class A, Class B....Class Z (any class extending BasePojo) and set different values for middleName and gender. I have tried a few other ideas, but I keep running into "incompatible type" errors. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it needs to be any more complex than this:

```
public static void setData(BasePojo pojo) {
    pojo.middleName = "Jason";
    pojo.gender = "male";
}
```

Not sure why you're involving Class objects.  They won't help you assign members.

Comment: It is because I really want to pass in Class A or Class B....Class Z, any class that extends BasePojo, and set different values for middleName and gender.

Comment: Class objects don't extend BasePojo.  Class objects represent a class definition, not an instance of that class.

Comment: Understood, I was able to get this to work an alternative way with having a better understanding of Class objects. Cheers!

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Since setData() accepts BasePojo as an argument you can call setData() even passing instances of A,B or any subclass of BasePojo as an argument.